# How to use a shared Queue between 2 processes in C#?

Tags: c#

I use C# (MS visual studio 2010) to simulate the Producer-Consumer problem. I have 2 exe programs, one is Producer and another is Consumer. When they're executing, Producer will insert 100 integers into a Queue, while Consumer will remove them from that Queue in orderly way.

My problem is how to use a shared Queue between two processes, and in case I have to use inter-process communication to pass some small messages, which mechanism should I use (in Clipboard, COM, Data Copy, DDE, File Mapping, Mailslots, Pipes, RPC, Windows Sockets)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a message queuing technology such as [MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing). Look into this to see if it would suit your requirements. You could use this alongside [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) which gives you the full pub/sub model off the shelf and is relatively easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I would think of using a database transaction table with concurrency control on the table between multiple read/writes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It would be far easier if the two processes were converted into threads within the same process, so they could directly share memory.

Barring that, you could use Memory-mapped I/O to establish a region of shared memory between the processes and a named mutex to ensure that only one thread accesses it as a time. You would have to write your own queue over a raw pointer, which is easy to get wrong.

It's possible for a queue to be lockless, even in this case, but that's much harder to pull off, and probably not worth it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm studying about IPC so there's no need for a multi-thread program. I have a new problem, I want to use a file as buffer, Producer program writes data into it while Consumer program read data from it. Since buffer always has a size limit, I have to remove one line each time read data from it. Google said to remove a line from file I have to rewrite into a temporary file, then overwrite existing file. Is there a better way to delete the first line from file?

Comment: Yes, treat it as a circular buffer. In other words, keep track of the start and end (initially, both point to the front). When you add, push the end back. When you read, push the front forward. At the end of the buffer, just wrap. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer for details and links.